# Angular, Laravel $http service. No data are displayed in html table

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I'm trying to write an simple CRUD operation to show posts list in table in my laravel aplication. I connect laravel with angular by using service $http. The problem is that data are not being displayed in table I see only empty rows.

Below I show my laravel controller function:

```
 public function index(){

    $posts = DB::table('posts')->join('categories','posts.category_id','=','categories.id')->
            join('users','posts.user_id','=','users.id')
            ->select('posts.id','posts.topic','categories.category_name','posts.created_at','users.name')->limit(3)->get();


    return response()->json($posts,200); 

}
```

Http Request in web.php file:

```
Route::get('api/posts','postsApiController@index');
```

My angular controller code with $http service:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap','ngSanitize','ngAnimate']).constant('API_URL', 'http://localhost:8000/api/');
app.controller('postsController', function($scope, $http, API_URL) {

     $http({

         method: 'GET',
         url: API_URL + "posts",


     }).then(function successCallback(response){

         $scope.posts = response;

     }, function errorCallback(response){


     });

});
```

In Google chrome Developer Tools, in overlap network I see response:

```
[{"id":9,"topic":"Odkrycie gwiazdy z ezgoplanet\u0105","category_name":"popularnonaukowe","created_at":"2017-04-16 17:38:59","name":"szarik"},{"id":18,"topic":"Post ze zdj\u0119ciem","category_name":"popularnonaukowe","created_at":"2017-05-07 15:30:52","name":"szarik"},{"id":21,"topic":"Testowy post","category_name":"popularnonaukowe","created_at":"2017-05-26 17:40:07","name":"szarik"}]
```

Here is part of my blade.php template where I'd like to display Received data:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-hover"> 
            <thead> 
                <tr> 
                    <th>Topic</th> 
                </tr>
            </thead> 
            <tbody> 
                <tr ng-repeat="post in posts">
                    <td>@{{  post.topic}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

I see only empty rows :

```
<tbody> 

           <!-- ngRepeat: post in posts --><tr ng-repeat="post in posts" class="ng-scope">

               <td class="ng-binding"></td>

                    </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: post in posts --><tr ng-repeat="post in posts" class="ng-scope">

               <td class="ng-binding"></td>

                    </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: post in posts --><tr ng-repeat="post in posts" class="ng-scope">

               <td class="ng-binding"></td>

                    </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: post in posts --><tr ng-repeat="post in posts" class="ng-scope">

               <td class="ng-binding"></td>

                    </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: post in posts --><tr ng-repeat="post in posts" class="ng-scope">

               <td class="ng-binding"></td>

                    </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: post in posts -->
        </tbody>
```

I completely don't know why it dosen't work. Could someone help me how Could I properly receive this data? I would be very greateful.
Best regards

Comment: change ```$scope.posts = response;``` to ```$scope.posts = response.data;``` and test it

Comment: Thank you very much It does works properly ;)

Comment: your welcome , so please accept my answer if it help you

Answer (score 1):

you didn't get data of response

change your Javascript code like this:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap','ngSanitize','ngAnimate']).constant('API_URL', 'http://localhost:8000/api/');
app.controller('postsController', function($scope, $http, API_URL) {

     $http({

         method: 'GET',
         url: API_URL + "posts",


     }).then(function successCallback(response){

         $scope.posts = response.data;

     }, function errorCallback(response){


     });

});
```

you missed response.**data**;